# Is this a Ruby scope issue?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, date, scope

I'm not sure if this is a scope issue, or just something I'm not familiar with in Ruby.

I have a helper method in my `application_helper.rb` that takes the list of events out of the database and determines which one is closest to the current date. This method is then used to display a list of events and a "featured event".

The method evaluates all the conditions correctly, but does not correctly assign `featured_event` when the loop is finished.

I have two events seeded, one for "October 31st" and one for "August 24th".

```
def current_featured_event
  featured_event = Event.all.first #assigns 10/31
  for event in Event.all do
    if event.datetime.to_date < featured_event.datetime.to_date and event.datetime.to_date > Date.today
      event = featured_event #assigns 8/24
    end
  end
  binding.pry
  featured_event #still 10/31
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
event = featured_event #assigns 8/24
```

This assigns `event`, not `featured_event`. Further, `event`'s assignment is overwritten on the next iteration of your loop. I think you want:

```
featured_event = event #assigns 8/24
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `event` objects are Active Record objects. That means they live in the database, so you can't assign one to another. I would do something like this:

```
def current_featured_event
    featured_event = Event.order("datetime DESC").first #assigns 10/31
end
```

Or something like this, if you want something closest to your code:

```
def current_featured_event
    featured_event = Event.all.first #assigns 10/31
    for event in Event.all do
        if event.datetime.to_date < featured_event.datetime.to_date and event.datetime.to_date > Date.today
            featured_event = event #assigns 8/24
        end
    end
    binding.pry
    featured_event
end
```

I think you are just wrongly swapping the two variables.

Comment: Your first code snippet doesn't do what I want, I want the event with the date closest to today to be the featured event. Your second code snippet doesn't seem to be any different from what I've already got (other than what needed to be fixed).